# Lottie for Xamarin Android Not working properly its overlaping and producing unacepted animation in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-animation, lottie

I have installed the Lotie Animation[Com.Airbnb.Android.Lottie] plugin with version 3.0.6 in Native project and added json file in the asset folder
here is the loti animation layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       
        app:lottie_fileName="logo_color2.json"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
       app:lottie_renderMode="hardware"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Strommad AB"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:textColor="#CFCFCF"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the activity code

```
  [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
        MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity, Animator.IAnimatorListener
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                RequestWindowFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                Window.SetFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen,
                    (Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen));
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_Splash);

                var animationView = FindViewById<LottieAnimationView>(Resource.Id.animation_view);
                animationView.AddAnimatorListener(this);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {


            }
        }

        public void OnAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
        {
        }

        public void OnAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }

        public void OnAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
        {
        }

        public void OnAnimationStart(Animator animation)
        {
        }
    }
```

when animation starting its showing like this which is not the required output
[image]

when the animation start its producing output like above how i can fix this problem i search alot but doest find its issue in json file or in code file
below is the required output result.
[image]